# Carbon's queue 'auto-flushes' periodically

Tags: graphite

[image: Graphite]

Carbon's queue size gradually increases everyday and then drops off suddenly. The total metrics received also exhibits the sudden unexplained drop-off.

- The load-average of the system is constant and well within bounds.
- The disk too isn't the bottleneck.

Why, firstly is the queue being filled up, when the metric count is almost steady? Why is the queue behaving erratically?

Answer (score 0):

Carbon first caches incoming metrics in memory before flushing them to disk.  The frequency at which it does this is predetermined by the configuration, and not by the speed of the disks.

If the scale on your graph is in days that seems a little ridiculous - usually graphite will flush metrics to disk every few seconds.  Check your /etc/carbon/carbon.conf!

Comment: Duh! You speak the most obvious. My flush interval is 5min.